# C# - Get all properties of a generic type by reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

My code:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    // I need a method here
}

public abstract class ValueObject<T> where T : ValueObject<T>
{
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public Password Password { get; private set; }
}

public class Password : ValueObject<Password>
{
}
```

I need a method in the Entity class that gets all properties of type ValueObject

[Edit 1]

I've tried something like this:

```
    var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

    foreach(var property in properties)
    {
       var type = property.PropertyType;

       if (property.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueObject<type>)) // Here is an error in "type"
       {
            // Here is other unnecessary things. Some things I already know how to do.
       }
    }
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? We're not here to write code for you I'm afraid.

Comment: There is no difference between generic vs. non-generic type when you do reflection.